# Solr highlights returns empty value

Tags: c#, solr, solrnet

IM using SolrNet (Version: 0.4.0.2002)to Query and my class is My class is:

```
public class SolrSimpleArticle
{
    [SolrUniqueKey("articleid")]
    public string ArticleId { get; set; }
    [SolrField("bodytext")]
    public string BodyText { get; set; }
}
```

My problem is that I can't make highlights to work. My code for highlightning:

```
    var results = solr.Query(iql, new QueryOptions
            {
                Start = start,
                Rows = 20,
                Highlight = new HighlightingParameters
                {
                    Fields = new[] { "bodytext" },
                    AfterTerm = highlight,
                    Snippets = 20,
                    MaxAnalyzedChars = 100000,
                }
            });
```

The returned results is as follows:

```
highlightedtext: Object
e410a0ac: Array[1]
    0: Object
    Key: "bodytext"
    Value: Array[0]
    __proto__: Object
    length: 1
    __proto__: Array[0]
e410b729: Array[1]
    0: Object
    Key: "bodytext"
    Value: Array[0]
    length: 0
    __proto__: Array[0]
    __proto__: Object
    length: 1
    __proto__: Array[0]
```

I need to know how i can get the highlighted snippet for each result and why there is no elements in the value array?Am I doing something wrong here?

I tried the defaults mentioned in https://github.com/mausch/SolrNet/blob/master/Documentation/Highlighting.md
Same response though.

Comment: https://groups.google.com/forum/#!forum/solrnet